# R software histogram with all printed x values

Tags: r, plot, histogram

I have the following data

```
meterpiuimportanti[row_sub,]
      Meter Numero Nodi
 [1,]   608         107
 [2,]    51          89
 [3,]   197          81
 [4,]    52          81
 [5,]   192          21
 [6,]   110          14
 [7,]   171          13
 [8,]   114          12
 [9,]   252          11
[10,]   121          10
[11,]    94          10
[12,]   295           9
[13,]   341           9
[14,]   113           7
[15,]   118           5
[16,]   196           4
[17,]    91           3
[18,]    92           3
[19,]    96           3
[20,]   112           3
[21,]   345           3
[22,]   378           3
[23,]   386           3
[24,]    90           2
[25,]   105           2
[26,]   204           2
[27,]   374           2
[28,]   104           1
[29,]   287           1
[30,]   328           1
[31,]   414           1
```

I would like to have a full page (1024x768) histogram with x axis being the first column and Y as second column.
The problems are:
1) I don't know how to enlarge the page
2) I want that all x values must be printed on x axis and on the top of each box of the histogram I want to print the value of the y

Thanks for your help

Comment: PS sorry I forgot to say that I must use only the standard base libraries and the Igraph library

Comment: I tried 'code' n<-meterpiuimportanti[row_sub,]  hist(n,xaxt='n')  axis(side=1, at=n[,1], labels=n[,1])      but it not what i want

Comment: Do you want an actual histogram (so that the x axis stays continuous and the distance actually represents something) or do you want a bargraph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the code below. It uses the grDevices package. I can't remember for sure, but I think it comes with the base install.

```
 df <-read.csv("/Data/test1.csv") #read
 png(filename="output.png", width=1024, height=768) #open graphics
 df <- df[order(df$x),]  #order data source
 mp <- barplot(df$y,axes=F)  #plot w/o labels
 #add value labels
 text(cex=1.5, x=mp, y=df$y+par("cxy")[2]/2+1, round(df$y,2), xpd=TRUE)
 axis(1,at=mp,labels=df$x, las=2)   #add x labels, make'm vertical
 axis(2,seq(0,max(df$y),round(max(df$y)/20))) #add y labels
 dev.off()
```

[image]

Comment: Note that this isn't a histogram

Comment: @Dason, The question specifically asked: "I want that all x values must be printed on x axis and on the top of each box of the histogram I want to print the value of the y." That makes the X axis categorical. Hence barplot.

Comment: I don't automatically jump to the conclusion that they want X to be categorical.  It could be that they want an extremely cleaned up version of: `j <- rep(d[,1],d[,2]);hist(j,breaks=seq(min(j),max(j),by=1));axis(1,d[,1],d[,1])` with the labels above as well (where d is obtained from@MaratTalipov's answer.

Comment: It's perfectly possible, if you want to assume column 2 is a freq column. Feel free to add that as an answer, if you wish. I think my version is more easily readable, especially in terms of the x axis.

Comment: I made no claims about readability and in fact implied that it would need to be cleane up a lot. There is the issue that with the bar plot you distort the spacing between the x values. It really comes down to what OP actually wants.

Comment: yup. comes down to the op.

Comment: @SerbanTanasa Thanks, your example was the one i asked for, I had to change slightly some use of the Matrix df and it worked in perfect way.

Comment: @Dason, thanks for your suggestion I tried both solution from you and Serban and the Serban result was more clear in terms of readability of the results (for my purposes, of course) because of following reason: 1) in your plot the x labels were overlapped during the plot 2) not all the x values were printed on the plot 3) the values of y were not printed on the top of the plot.

Comment: @SerbanTanasa just for general information the R base standard packages are enough to make your code run

Comment: @alexfort yeah I said it would need to be cleaned up. You weren't clear with what you actually wanted. You said you wanted a histogram but ultimately went with a bar chart. I wrote that code in about a minute but you could get the labels to not overlap with some effort. I didn't even bother with putting the y values over the bars since all I was doing was illustrating that you lose the sense of magnitude on the x axis when using a bar chart. So now you know there is a difference between histogram and bar chart.

Comment: @Dason, no problem, i didn't need the magnitude, the results I needed were anyway obtained and the results are https://plus.google.com/u/0/115505398072903675944/posts/baKmELMahhL?pid=6111974415482387810&oid=115505398072903675944

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the `ggplot2` package:

**Code**

```
library(ggplot2)

png('~/x.png',width=1024,height=768)
ggplot(d) + 
  aes(x=factor(V1,levels=V1),y=V2) +
  geom_bar(position='dodge',stat='identity') +
  xlab('V1') + 
  geom_text(aes(label=V2), position=position_dodge(width=0.9), vjust=-0.25)
dev.off()
```

**Result**

[image]

**Data Set**

```
d <- structure(list(V1 = c(608L, 51L, 197L, 52L, 192L, 110L, 171L, 
114L, 252L, 121L, 94L, 295L, 341L, 113L, 118L, 196L, 91L, 92L, 
96L, 112L, 345L, 378L, 386L, 90L, 105L, 204L, 374L, 104L, 287L, 
328L, 414L), V2 = c(107L, 89L, 81L, 81L, 21L, 14L, 13L, 12L, 
11L, 10L, 10L, 9L, 9L, 7L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("V1", "V2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-31L))
```

Comment: Thanks @Marat Talipov, unfortunately I can't use ggplot2 package, but your plot was really cool !